# "Callback" in Visual Basic?

Tags: vb.net, dll, callback

I have a new problem. I just learned how to create and import DLLs in Visual Basic 12. I've already gone far with it. But my problem is, I don't know how to call on objects that belong to another project.

What I mean is:

I have a 2 projects. One is the EXE that calls the DLL. The other is obviously the DLL itself.

Here's the DLL:

```
Public Class sys_auth
    Private cs As String
    Private pw As String
    Public Function auth()
        cs = TextBoxFromOtherProject.Text           [HOW DO I DO THIS?!]
        pw = AnotherTextBoxFromOtherProject.Text    [HOW DO I DO THIS?!]
        Select Case cs
            Case "MehName"
                If pw = "MehPassword" Then
                    MsgBox("Authentication successful!", MsgBoxStyle.Information, "Success")
                    Return True
                Else
                    Return False

                End If

            Case "YoName"
                If pw = "YoPassword" Then
                    MsgBox("Authentication successful!", MsgBoxStyle.Information, "Success")
                    Return True
                Else
                    Return False

                End If

            Case Else
                Return False

        End Select

    End Function
End Class
```

How can I call it?

Answer (score 0):

You probably just want to add two parameters to your method, e.g.:

```
Public Class sys_auth

    Public Function auth(cs As String, pw As String) As Boolean
        Select Case cs
            Case "MehName"
            ...
```

and call it from your other project:

```
Dim result = New sys_auth().auth(TextBoxFromOtherProject.Text, AnotherTextBoxFromOtherProject.Text)
```